# How to hide appscripts when making copy of the google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to don't share or hide the 'Attached Apps Script file' when making a copy of google spreadsheet?

Currently, I can see the script file when making a copy of google spreadsheet from master spreadsheet.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think you can hide it, but as the linked answer says, you can remove it completely.

Comment: painful. I actually dont want to expose my script after making a copy of the spreadsheet